# Variable is not working in GitHub workflow loop

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I am new to GitHub Scripts,

My requirement is retrieve the list of Json files available in repository and calling the API passing filename as a data in GitHub workflow.

Working Scripts are,

```
jobs:
  Test:
    runs-on: self-hosted   
    outputs:
      filelist: ${{ steps.finding-files.outputs.filelist }}
      response: ${{ steps.apicall.outputs.response }}
    steps:
    # -----------------------------------
    # list of json files from GitHub repo
    # -----------------------------------
      - name: Finding the list of JSON files
        id: finding-files
        run: |
          echo ::set-output name=filelist::$(find . -name '*.json' -print)
    # -----------------------------------
    # API Call
    # -----------------------------------
      - name: API Call
        id: apicall
        run: | 
          for i in ${{ steps.finding-files.outputs.filelist }}; do
             echo filename : $(basename "${i}") //It display the filename with .json extension
             
         echo filename=$(basename "${i}") >> $GITHUB_ENV
     
             echo ::set-output name=response::$(curl --location ${{ secrets.API_URL }} --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --header 'Authorization:Basic ${{ secrets.ENC }}' --data '{"filename" : "{$env:filename}"}')
          done
```

I'm facing the issue while passing the filename in API call, It is not return the filename.

I've tried "$(basename '${i}')" directly in the API call but it returns as a string since it's under double quoted.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `set-output` is deprecated. Use `GITHUB_OUTPUT` instead. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter. Looks like your self-hosted runner is Linux based and you're using bash but `$env:filename` is PowerShell syntax. And, when an env var is set with `GITHUB_ENV`, it will be available in the next steps, not in the same one. You need to update your workflow accodingly.

Comment: BTW, you can run `basename` as part of `find` like this: `find . -name '*.json' -exec basename {} \;` and it'll return the filenames only.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem for the command and inputs,

Kindly advise me here how we can pass the filename into the curl call.
FYI...I've tried the below options.
--data '{"filename" : $i}' output is deserialize() error
--data '{"filename" : "$i"}' output is $i
--data '{"filename" : "{$i}"}' output is @$i

my expectations is $i should replaced as filename.json.

Comment: Sure, no problem. You need to escape quotes to make it a valid JSON e.g. `"{\"filename\":\"$FILENAME\"}"`. I updated it in my answer. Please test that on your side. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`set-output` is deprecated. [Use `GITHUB_OUTPUT` instead.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter)

Looks like your self-hosted runner is Linux based and you're using bash but `$env:filename` is PowerShell syntax. Also, when an env var is set, it will be available in the next steps, not in the same one. You need to update your workflow accordingly.

You can run `basename` as part of `find` like this:

```bash
find . -name '*.json' -exec basename {} \;
```

Also, the JSON in your `curl` command is not valid. The quotes need to be properly escaped:

```json
"{\"filename\":\"$FILENAME\"}"
```

---

Here is your updated workflow without setting env var or output parameter (not tested, you need to test it on your side):

```yaml
jobs:
  Test:
    runs-on: self-hosted   
    steps:
    - name: API Call
      run: |
        FILENAMES="$(find . -name '*.json' -exec basename {} \;)"
        for FILENAME in $FILENAMES; do
          echo "Running API call for $FILENAME"
          RESPONSE="$(curl --location '${{ secrets.API_URL }}' --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic ${{ secrets.ENC }}' --data "{\"filename\":\"$FILENAME\"}")"
          echo "Setting env var [RESPONSE_${FILENAME}=$RESPONSE]"
          echo "RESPONSE_${FILENAME}=$RESPONSE" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        done
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Azeem for your guidelines,

Finally, I achieved and the script is,

```
jobs:
  Test:
    runs-on: self-hosted   
    steps:
      - name: API Call
        run: |
          FILENAMES=$(find . -name '*.json' -exec basename {} \;)
          for FILENAME in $FILENAMES; do
             echo "Running API call for $FILENAME"         
             echo "Response Message is $(curl --location ${{ secrets.API_URL }} --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --header 'Authorization:Basic ${{ secrets.ENC }}' --data "{\"filename\" : \"$FILENAME\"}")"
          done
```